# phpDocumentor in Zend Studio ignores properties declared using PHP 5 syntax?

Tags: php, zend-studio, phpdoc

I'm using vanilla Zend Studio 8 on Mac OS X 10.6 with a simple test project.

When I generate documentation using phpDocumentor (using the default settings), the resulting documentation does not include any class properties - even though I wrote valid docblocks for them.

Example:

```
/**
 * The number of characters of the text.
 * It is used to prevent the program from operating beyond the end of the text.
 * @var int
 */
public $length;
```

The above property doesn't appear anywhere in the generated documentation.

However, if I change `public` to `var` (i.e. changing my code from PHP 4 to PHP 5 syntax), then the properties appear in the documentation just fine.

Any ideas on what is causing this problem or how to fix it?

**EDIT:**  I have just installed phpDocumentor separately from the Zend Studio installation, and attempted to generate the documentation that way - it works perfectly outside of Zend Studio and all of the properties show up as well as the highlighted source code.

So this seems to only be an issue with either Zend Studio itself, its integrated copy of phpDocumentor, or its integrated copy of PHP.

Comment: This is something that baffled me as well when i tried using phpdocumentor a while back.

Comment: use the most actual version. However, phpDocumentor seems to lack of development for a while now. Consider using some other tool, like  docblox.

Comment: phpDoc seems fine for my needs.  Although it would be nice to be able to just generate the documentation from right inside Zend Studio, I don't mind using the web interface on a stand-alone installation of phpDoc.  I might look into other documentation packages, thanks.  Still would be nice to get a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe PHPDocumentor is not supported anymore, I too am looking for an alternative. If you are on a mac, try and use the Apple Open Source Doxygen, it looks really cool and I believe it is install be default on OSX http://developer.apple.com/tools/creatingdocsetswithdoxygen.html